# break-on-modify in firebug?

Tags: javascript, debugging, firebug

I'm having trouble tracking down a bug which is causing a button to get disabled.

Is there a way to have firebug break if the button state is touched in javascript?

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure. Maybe registering some JavaScript code to the `onChange` event of this button and having a breakpoint there?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can break on attribute change
http://getfirebug.com/doc/breakpoints/demo.html